# Not receiving email confirmation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, subscription, email-verification

I have subscribed to a tag but I do not get the confirmation email that is sent. It is not in my spam folder.

Comment: Does it happen with one tag only? Do you get confirmations for other tags?

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/13978/hippocms?subscribe=yee-haw) you should see "resend confirmation email", do you get email after clicking it?

Comment: I am only subscribed to one tag. I have resent the confirmation email multiple times.

Comment: Next question, do you get any emails from Stack Exchange? Did you get any in the past?

Comment: I'm getting notifications about this question, but I haven't actually ever received any other emails here. I have another account that has also been used on stack exchange and that one does receive mail. They are both Google accounts, but this one is  company account and the other one is a regular gmail account.

Comment: So maybe the email is blocked in the company level, e.g. some firewall. Worth contacting your company network administrator and ask.

Comment: You could have said from the beginning you already confirmed it once....

Comment: I checked with our infra department and nothing is blocked on our end but they also say no email has been received by our servers either. Sorry for not being more complete in my original description.

Comment: Not relevant, no email was sent because you already confirmed the subscription. If you will remove the subscription and subscribe again you should get a new confirmation email.

Comment: I've unsubscribed and resubscribed. I did get a confirmation email. Will have to wait for a new question to see if notifications work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are already subscribed to the tag with a confirmed email address.

When we see that (and given you have not changed anything in your subscription), we don't send a confirmation email (after all, the email address is confirmed, *as is that specific tag subscription*).